# Business Catalyst Is there a way for web apps to have comments?

Tags: comments, blogs, business-catalyst

I am currently working on a site where the client would like to have a blog where in list view their is a custom sized image and then the image changes size on the detail page. I decided it was best to use a web app for this feature as the blog section of business catalyst doesn't have an image field I can pull from however, the customer also wants comments is there a way to have comments with web apps without it being overly hard for the client to handle.

Or is there a way to use the blog feature in bc and have the image resize to a larger size on the detail page?

Your help is greatly Appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: For comments on webapp items, the best bet is a 3rd party plugin such as [Disqus](https://disqus.com/websites/) or [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments). There's not currently an effective way of showing images on blog posts, even combining webapps with the blog module.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following;

1. As previously stated above you can use the Disqus comment module to
   manage the comments.  Here is a great video from Dave Haggblad doing a BC Sandpile that
   will show you how to integrate this.
   http://www.bcsandpile.com/_blog/Meeting_Chalkboard/post/spam-free-comments-with-dave-haggblad/
2. If you create the blog as a WebApp you can get BC to dynamically resize your images to achieve the smaller thumbnail on the listview and larger image on the details page by adding some simple code.  Follow the link to the BC documentation below to see it in action. https://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-2145

Hope this helped.

Don